# Passing an array to function

Tags: c, arrays

```
int avg(int *p);

int main()
{
    int i, average, mark[5];
    int arr[5];

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++);
    {
        arr[i] = scanf_s("%d\n", &mark[i]);
    }
    average = avg(arr);
}

int avg(int *p)
{
    int j, total = 0, avg;

    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        total += p[j];
    }
    avg = total / 5;
    return avg;
}
```

This program did not cause any errors.But while running I am getting `"Run-Time Check Failure #2 -stack around the variable "mark" was corrupted.` Can some one please explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Another reason for [Egyptian brackets](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)/K&R style: you have a (probably unintended) semicolon after your `for` in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

why you are using semicolon at the end of for loop..?

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++);

remove that semicolon and check

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++);
```

I don't think you want that semicolon there!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly about the fix:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = scanf_s("%d\n", &mark[i]);
    }
```

This is just okey. Now reason of `Run-Time Check Failure #2 -stack around the variable "mark" was corrupted` :
when you run:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++);
```

After this line `i = 5` Now you are doing `arr[i] = scanf_s("%d\n", &mark[i]);` Now `arr[5]` is not a leagal area for you. This is the reason of your error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a little explanation to the other answers.

The `for` loop does essentially nothing, except incrementing `i` until it is n longer `< 5`.

So if you leave the `for` loop, you have `i = 5`, and this is used for accessing `arr` and `mark`. Neither `arr[5]` nor `mark[5]` is valid, so your error happens.